# Getting OSM Nodes and Ways from own Database

Tags: openstreetmap, routing

we need OSM Nodes and Ways to use with our own routing algorithm, but we don't want to load all of the data in the RAM of our Server. So we thought about saving all the data in a database and only load some parts for each routing request. 
I already had a look at osm2psql and osm2pgrouting but they all don't store just the ways and nodes. It's important to load only ways and nodes as in our special case we have to use our own algorithm.
So the question basically consists of 2 parts:

1. Let's say we got an osm-file and want to import it in a database. What tools are good for that?
2. How can we read data fast from the database with the input of a bounding box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you discovered, osm2pgsql and osm2pgrouting are not the tools to use. These tools create dedicated spatial schema's and actually ***convert*** the raw data (especially in the case of osm2pgsql and its support for creating PostGIS multipolygons), instead of giving you the 'raw' data to do your own processing on.

I think for your particular use case, you should be looking at something like [Osmosis](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis) to do the job.